# apostrophe cms version 2.65.0 giving error on running project

Tags: mongodb, npm, apostrophe-cms

I am upgrading the apostrophe version from `2.62.0` to `2.65.0`. While upgrading I have added the mongo driver-3 into setting also still running the project, I am getting the error :

> (node:116248) Warning: a promise was created in a handler at project/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:167:37 but was not returned from it, see xxxx

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only a warning. `bluebird` thinks we might be unintentionally ending a promise chain, but it is intentional and nothing is wrong. It was addressed in Apostrophe 2.68.0 according to bluebird's instructions for silencing it where appropriate, so update to the latest with `npm update` and it will stop.

Comment: Thanks Tom! By updating the apostrophe latest version has solved the issue.